# Matching unique Id's from two mysql tables, my query is only pulling a portion of them

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I have my tables. I know this question has been asked a million times but I can't seem to figure out why it's only pulling a portion of the transaction ID's from one of my tables.

I have two tables. author and tab2.

author looks like so and the unique id is COL9:

```
COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4  COL5  COL6  COL7  COL8  COL9
data  data  data  data  data  data  data  data  6314085733
```

My other table is tab2 and there is only one column in it:

```
COL1  
6300798484
6300917409
6301563169
```

**UPDATE:** I just realized that there are two spaces in quiet a few of the COL1 fields. I changed the data type to varchar(10) to eliminate those extra spaces and reran the query.. still nothing.

My query is like so:

```
SELECT b.Col1, a.* 
FROM author a 
JOIN tab2 b 
ON b.COL1 = a.COL9 
ORDER BY a.COL9 DESC
```

I know there has to be more than 600 and the results I'm getting are:

> Showing rows 0 - 24 (29 total, Query took 7.2141 sec) [COL9: 6319720972 - 6302432564]

Comment: Is that three rows in COL1?

Comment: no there's roughly 700 in COL1.. i just didn't want to be redundant and about 1000 in COL9

Comment: is there about 600 equal values in a.Col9 and b.col1?

Comment: Yes, i'm thinking around 670.

Comment: @Rad what is the data type of a.Col9 and b.col1 columns?

Comment: One was varchar(10) and the other was varchar(14).. i changed them both to 14 but there should never be more than 10 digits in this query. good suggestion..

Comment: I just realized in tab2 column towards the end of the list quiet a few of the fields have two blank spaces at the end of the cell. ack!

Comment: try using left join @Rad

Answer (score 0):

If COL1 and COL9 holds numeric values use a cast to get the data.

```
SELECT b.Col1, a.* 
FROM author a 
JOIN tab2 b 
ON CAST(b.COL1 AS BIGINT) = CAST(a.COL9 AS BIGINT)
ORDER BY CAST(a.COL9 AS BIGINT) DESC;
```

Or you can use a TRIM.
Trim is not by default available in mssql.
first create a Scalar valued function.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Trim]
    (
        -- Add the parameters for the function here
        @pString VARCHAR(2000)
    )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
    AS
    BEGIN   
        RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@pString, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')));
    END

GO
```

Use the below query

```
SELECT b.Col1, a.* 
FROM author a 
JOIN tab2 b 
ON dbo.Trim(b.COL1) = dbo.Trim(a.COL9)
ORDER BY dbo.Trim(a.COL9) DESC;
```

Comment: I'm not seeing it but it says I have a syntax error on line 4.

Comment: Any Idea why this syntax is broken?

Comment: syntax looks to be proper.
can you paste the sql you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TRIM, like this:

```
SELECT b.Col1, a.* 
FROM author a 
JOIN tab2 b 
ON TRIM(b.COL1) = TRIM(a.COL9) 
ORDER BY a.COL9 DESC
```

Comment: Aziz, this did not work; wouldn't trim being doing the same as me changing the varcar to only allow 10?

Comment: How may i add another condition, I would like to match emails too and list out all duplicates. I think that's the problem.

Comment: @Rad To add a condition, `WHERE` clause can be used.